# Trying to install Visual Studio 2015 community edition but install window becomes invisible

Tags: visual-studio

<strike>This issue is driving me crazy.  I'm on a corporately controlled network but have local administrator rights.  This issue is happening with all versions of Visual Studio installer where you initiate the install, then you see the initial splash screen and then that vanishes and it looks like nothing is there.  But if you click and drag that area you can see the window borders during the drag.  Some portions of the invisible window even respond to mouse clicks.  There's even a task bar indication that is blank when you hover over it. I can't even update the current 2013 installation to SP5 because even that window behaves the same way.</strike>

However, it just totally hangs the install and since I can't see the install options I don't know if there's a failure or it's just waiting on me to do something.

I've seen several posts about this outside of here but all of them lead to a dead-end.

I have installed Studio on this machine before - actually all versions since 2005 and never have seen this issue until it started about 2 months ago.  I did updates galore and all that.  Updated my video drivers, blah, blah, blah.  I've even tried remoting into this this box and seeing if that would alter the display enough to see what is going on...all to no avail.

The box is beefy (i5, 16GB, 500GB SSD...triple display, etc...) so it more than meets the requirements.

When I try to install any version of Visual Studio, the install window briefly appears and then disappears.  However, it is still there, just 100% transparent.  Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Sounds like a super user site issue, not being mean but this ain't the place to vent about software not installing properly. If not this place would be crowded XD

Comment: Really?  Venting?  No I'm not venting I'm genuinely asking if anyone has seen this before.

Comment: Okay why don't  your rephrase, hey I am not closing the thing I am actually requesting it be moved to Super User. If it were other people they close it. But instead of saying your feelings try describing the problem. No need to write this for example: "This issue is driving me crazy."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally find an answer to the invisible install dialog question, it is however not an adequate solution, but an answer.  I have to run only one monitor then the install dialog is visible and things proceed normally.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to disable the graphics card I have on my computer and run on onboard graphics card. It seems that the issue is with the graphics, so forcing the system to use the "regular" graphics card did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I have to use /Full /Passive from the command line to install on a build server. I would prefer less flashy installer for a more robust one. I am sure its a combination of the graphics card etc. But other installers work.